# JavaScript create clickable href

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, append, href

I have a simple stupid question. I want to add a URL which is clickable in JavaScript to my HTML

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.at');
$("#upcomingEvents").append('Please check our website. ' + a);
```

The URL appears, but it is not clickable, how can I change that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put some text inside the link so there is something to click:

```
a.innerText='click me!';
```

And then you can't concatenate a string to a DOM element.

```
$("#upcomingEvents").append('Please check our website.');
$("#upcomingEvents").append(a);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/arojad/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
$("#upcomingEvents").append('Please check our website. ');
$("#upcomingEvents").append(a);
```

The `+` operator causes the DOMNode to be cast to a string, you don't want that.

Comment: Might as well use `.append().append()`